# How to look up census tracts in Python using FCC's API and iterating over a list of dicts?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm really new to Python and have been looking all over for how to do this for days and am still totally baffled. I pulled data from a city's website in json format, and it's displaying as a list of dicts, e.g.:

```
[{'abbr': '14ASSB01',
  'id': '7',
  'mdtlat': '423374191',
  'mdtlong': '-830800061',
  'name': '14TH & ASH',
  'off': '0.4899',
  'on': '1.74422',
  'schedule': 'April 23, 2012 Schedule Data',
  'service': 'Avg Weekday',
  'stop_order': '0',
  'stopactivi': '2.23413',
  'the_geom': {'coordinates': [-83.08001, 42.33742], 'type': 'Point'},
  'trips': '32',
  'wgslat': '42.33742',
  'wgslong': '-83.08001'},
 {'abbr': '14BLSB01',
  'id': '9',
  'mdtlat': '423716251',
  'mdtlong': '-831006789',
  'name': '14TH & BLAINE',
  'off': '14.45024',
  'on': '21.12781',
  'schedule': 'April 23, 2012 Schedule Data',
  'service': 'Avg Weekday',
  'stop_order': '0',
  'stopactivi': '35.57805',
  'the_geom': {'coordinates': [-83.10068, 42.37163], 'type': 'Point'},
  'trips': '32',
  'wgslat': '42.37163',
  'wgslong': '-83.10068'},
```

I want to use the FCC's lat/long to census block conversion API and add a new key:value pair to each dict in my list with the result.

To pull the original data, I was able to do

```
import json
import requests


endpoint = "url..."
response = requests.get(endpoint)
results - response.text
data = json.loads(results)
```

But I can't figure out how to do two things: iterate over my list of dicts with the call to the census block conversion API, or how to add the result (the census block number) as a new key:value pair in each dict.

I tried doing this after moving my data into a pandas dataframe, but got a "string indices must be integers" error (even though the lat/long fields had been converted to float:

```
endpoint = 'http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?format=json'

params = {'latitude' : [(num['wgslat']) for num in busso],
          'longitude' : [(num['wgslong']) for num in busso]
}


url = requests.Request('GET', endpoint, params=params).prepare()
url

resp = requests.get(endpoint)
resul = response.text
```

If anyone has *any* suggestions/hints on a route I could take to run all my lat/longs through the FCC API and return the new census block information as a new key:value pair -- or as a new column in a dataframe -- I'd be incredibly appreciative!

Comment: your question is broad ,list your problems clearly step by step

Comment: You're throwing too much stuff at us. I quit reading halfway. To maximize your chances of getting help, please boil this whole thing down to a [mcve].